# Be $B=\left\{x\mid \frac{1}{2}<|x|\le1\right\}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $Y=[-1.1]$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $B=\left\{x\mid \frac{1}{2}<|x|\le1\right\}$.

I know that $B$ is not open in the straight, because we will have problem in the points $-1$ and $1$ because we can not get a ball centered on them entirely contained in $B$.

But because $B$ would be open in $Y$, I haven't been able to see that yet. I know that those opened in $Y$ would be the intersections of the common open of the straight with the $Y$. So how do I prove $B$ is open at $Y$?

Comment: What is $A$ here?

Comment: Open sets in $Y$ are of the form $O\cap Y$ with $O$ open in $\Bbb R$.  Your set is of this form.

Answer (score 3):

$B=Y\cap\underbrace{[(-2,-1/2)\cup(1/2,2)]}_\text{open in $\Bbb R$}$

Comment: I didn't quite understand.

Comment: $V=(-2,-1/2)\cup(1/2,2)$ is open set in "the straight", so $B=Y\cap V$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: By induced topology?

Comment: Open sets of the topology induced on $Y$ are of the form $Y\cap V$ where $V$ is open set in "the straight"